# No wifi "Intel Corporation Wireless 3160" and the webcam is not detected also on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, internet, camera

I am using Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 64-bit with GNOME(3.14.1) in my computer.

My problems are really "simple":

- I don't have wifi (no drivers).
- My webcam is not detected either.

Just wanted to point out that I have ethernet.

PS: I have already installed the broadcom drivers for wifi but they are not working (`sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms`)

Edit: The output of the command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is:

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 [8086:0070]
```

Comment: What's the hardware? Do you know what wifi adapter you have?

Comment: Welcome to U&L ,To test your webcam , Install `cheese` and run it `sudo apt install cheese && cheese` , to get the exact driver info , please [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/354789/edit) by adding the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: Thanks for the help in advance! I have edited my question. I had already tried to use cheese, webcam is not recognized.

Comment: Please install `hwinfo` then run : `hwinfo --usb` from the terminal , you will get some information about the webcam then update with the webcam info or here :https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @GAD3R here it is https://pastebin.com/jKnM8nN9
I'd like to point out that the webcam is built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `lspci` command : The required package is the [`firmware-iwlwifi`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/firmware-iwlwifi) (not the `broadcom-sta-dkms`)

According to [the official website](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) you should upgrade your kernel version (`> 4.2`). The easy way is to install the latest backports kernel's :

add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

then update :

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Run the following command to get the available `linux-image`

```
apt-cache search linux-image
```

Install the `linux-base` from backports:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-base
```

Install the `linux-image` and the `linux-headers`:

```
apt-get install linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 \
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
```

Remove the `broadcom-sta-dkms` :

```
apt-get remove broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Reboot your system then install the `firmware-iwlwifi` package from backports or download  the `iwlwifi-3160-ucode-25.30.14.0.tgz`  from the [official website](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) then copy the `iwlwifi-3160-14.ucode` firmware to your `/lib/firmware`:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
```

Or

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-3160-ucode-25.30.14.0.tgz
tar xvf iwlwifi-3160-ucode-25.30.14.0.tgz
cd iw*
cp iwlwifi-3160-14.ucode /lib/firmware
modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: followed your instructions. did not work though :/
Note: modprobe iwlwifi gave me command not found. with sudo modprobe iwlwifi I was able to run it but nothing happened.

Comment: run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` to bring up the wifi interface

Comment: `wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device`

Comment: Running `ifconfig` I can see that I have no wireless interface (only eth0 and lo).

Comment: what is the result of `ls /lib/firmware | grep iw*`

Comment: Here it is https://pastebin.com/pPeXsC0Q

Comment: Remove `broadcom-sta-dkms` package then `rmmod wl iwlwifi` and `modprobe iwlwifi` as root

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked after removing the `broadcom-sta-dkms` ! I'm actually writing this message via wifi!

Comment: Maybe you can help me with the webcam too?

Comment: @Skinish Great! what is the output of `lsusb` ?

Comment: here it is https://pastebin.com/MeYpjq09

Comment: What is the result of `sudo modprobe uvcvideo && cheese`

Comment: `** Message: cheese-application.vala:211: Error during camera setup: No device found`
(...)

Comment: @Skinish see here http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Webcam-HOWTO/#MODELS